# Difference between Task.Result and Request response

Tags: .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I am sending Httprequests using tasks and capturing their response. In my code I wanted to know what is the true difference between (HttpWebResponse)t.Result and HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse
Here is the actual code:

```
public void pageCheck(WebSite webParam){
    //SomeCode omitted
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    try{
        Task<WebResponse> task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        myReq.BeginGetResponse,myReq.EndGetResponse,null);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //some code omitted
                var responseCode = (HttpWebResponse) t.Result;

                //do some things with response code
                response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
                //other code omitted
            });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetResponse executes the request and returns the result while t.Result doesn't execute anything. It simply contains the result from an asynchronous invocation using BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse.

If the original operation hasn't finished, t.Result will actually block until a result is available. In your case, this won't happen as ContinueWith executes only after the asynchronous invocation created by FromAsync finishes.

As is, your code executes the request twice, once when you call FromAsync and another time when you call GetResponse.